# Similarity between cardamom and rosemary

Tags: flavor, spices, herbs, smell

I have noticed a similarity in taste between cardamom and rosemary.

I was wondering if anyone could explain to me, perhaps from the point of view of phenols or chemical components or mixtures or flavonoids or anything that can contribute to flavor (probably not texture), that can explain this phenomenon.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

[This flavor data base](https://cosylab.iiitd.edu.in/flavordb/) is really interesting to play with.  I did a [search for cardamom](https://cosylab.iiitd.edu.in/flavordb/entity_details?id=327).  Then I did a [search for rosemary](https://cosylab.iiitd.edu.in/flavordb/entity_details?id=264).  You'll note that they have many flavor compounds in common.  That would certainly explain your experience.  [Here is a paper about the database.](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5753196/) If you are interested in this sort of thing, [this is a great book](https://www.penguinrandomhouse.com/books/302507/nose-dive-by-harold-mcgee/).